# When was the first Beis Hamikdash built?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, masechet-moed-katan

The Gemara in Moed Katan 9 said that the Beis Hamikdash was inaugurated right after being finished, while I've seen a [Medrash](http://www.chabadofla.com/media/pdf/690/fwwG6909400.pdf) that it was finished in Cheshvan and the inauguration was put on hold.

Does anyone talk about this contradiction?

Comment: Citing this Medrash inside would improve this question

Comment: Better link for you (מדרש is at the bottom of [this page](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=10&perek=6&mefaresh=shimoni) [ref Shimoni I Melachim 184]) (got the reference from your link)

Answer (score 1):

From the [Codex Judaica](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0967037832) pg 94:

The 7th of Tishrei Shlomo Hamelech gathered all of bnei Yisrael to honor the entry of Aron into the new bais Hamikdash. They celebrated for seven days even on Yom kippur,then they celabrated sukkos (Melachim 1:8:1-6 ,Masheches Moed Katan 9, and shabbas 30a)
The Finishing touches to the new building were completed in Chesvan(Melachim 1:6:38) ,Ralbag Divrei Hayamim 2 :7:10,11)

The constructioin started in Iyar (Shmuel 2:5:11)