# What day of Cheshvan was the Beis Hamikdash built?

Tags: beis-hamikdash

The Posuk in Melachim (I:6:38) [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Noach.11.7?lang=bi):

> וּבַשָּׁנָה הָאַחַת עֶשְׂרֵה בְּיֶרַח בּוּל הוּא הַחֹדֶשׁ הַשְּׁמִינִי
> כָּלָה הַבַּיִת לְכׇל־דְּבָרָיו וּלְכׇל־מִשְׁפָּטָו וַיִּבְנֵהוּ
> שֶׁבַע שָׁנִים׃ and in the eleventh year, in the month of Bul—that is,
> the eighth month—the House was completed according to all its details
> and all its specifications. It took him seven years to build it.

Rashi there [explains](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.6.38?ven=Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_I_Kings.6.38.1&lang2=bi):

> בְּיֶרַח בּוּל. הוּא מַרְחֶשְׁוָן, שֶׁהָעֵשֶׂב בָּלָה בַשָּׂדֶה,
> וּבוֹלְלִין לַבְּהֵמָה מִן הַבַּיִת, מִלְּשׁוֹן: וַיָּבָל לַחֲמוֹרִים.
> In the month of Bul. This is [the month of] Mar Cheshvan; [when] the
> grass in the field decays, and cattle is given fodder from what is
> stored, from the expression “and he gave fodder [ויבל] to the donkeys.

Which particular day of Cheshvan was the Beis Hamikdash finished?

Comment: Based on the calendar linked in this question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47787/when-was-the-first-beis-hamikdash-built. It seems it was the first day of cheshvan

Comment: Thank you. This site says it was the 17th of Cheshvan without a source. https://meaningfulminute.org/cheshvan-the-best-time-to-cultivate-grit/